# Next.JS issue with build vs local dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

**Bug description**
I am working with a library called react-carousel from brainhubeu in NextJS. Even when I am using dynamic import with ssr:false, The build UI looks strange but the dev UI is perfectly fine.

dev UI -

[image]

I have recreated it in Codesandbox too (this one is for dev environment is running `npm run dev`)-
https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-volhard-460q8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

However when I build it and then run the build by using  `npm run build` && `npm run start` -

[image]

To recreate this in codesandbox -

1. In bottom right click on + sign for a new terminal
2. npm run build
3. npm run start  (I have already added   "start": "next start -p 8080" in the package.json file so a new tab will be created for the sandbox and can be accessed as https://460q8-8080.sse.codesandbox.io/ where 8080 signifies the port number )

**Expected behavior**
UI should be same as when seen with npm run dev.

**Question**

1. Why does my dev UI works fine but when I build and serve, the UI is strange. What exactly is the difference between npm run dev and npm run build && npm run start in context of NextJS?
2. Any solution to this problem?

**My attempts**

1. I have been trying to work on this problem and have asked this question on official Github discussions on NextJS. Couldnt find any answer.
2. I even created a Github Bug issue on react-carousel's Github, they couldn't help much.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. In my case, it was due to the difference between how I had set up (dev) and next build && next start. Take note of a few things to get it sorted -

1. If you have used an external library, chances are it doesn't support server-side rendering. I was using react-carousel from Brainhubeu and it having some issues. Resolve it by importing the library via [next/dynamic imports with ssr:false option](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr).
2. Another issue was that I was using/following an outdated boilerplate code for Tailwind and NextJS. Hence the way postcss.config.js was configured was error-prone. Here is the crux of the problem. at least for me - **During the dev, everything worked fine because postcss didn't purge any of the classes of third party plugins/libraries that I imported, however, they were being purged when I did npm run build and npm run start**

Now let's quickly see how you can solve this issue on your part -

1. Use the inbuilt purge option provided by TailwindCSS. For this, [use the official starter-code/boilerplate code from the NextJS team](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss). As they mention there - To control the generated stylesheet's filesize, this example uses Tailwind CSS' purge option to remove unused CSS.
2. Or you could try patching the problem if you don't want to go the previous way. I would only suggest this method if you are almost done with the project and just want to get this working because this is in no way a good solution. You will have to whitelist a bunch of css files from being purged. This is what I did but you can probably whitelist a lost more CSS classes as well -

```
// postcss.config.js 
  
const purgecss = [
  "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
  {
    content: [
      "./node_modules/@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css",
      "./node_modules/@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css.map",
      "./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/*.css",
      "./components/**/*.js",
      "./pages/**/*.js",
    ],
    defaultExtractor: (content) => {
      const broadMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g) || [];
      const innerMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s.()]*[^<>"'`\s.():]/g) || [];
      return broadMatches.concat(innerMatches);
    },
  },
];
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-import",
    "tailwindcss",
    "autoprefixer",
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [purgecss] : []),
  ],
};
```

Still I would suggest go the first way and copy your code from old repo to new, use SSR:false to use client-side libraries that hate SSR, and you should be good to go.

You can reach out to my Twitter [@toughyear](https://twitter.com/toughyear) if you need help with this.